# Ansible set_fact wget version

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to run the set_fact task at the start of my ansible-playbook to set a version and use it in my playbook.

I have tried to this and failing with incorrect syntax, I think

```
- name: "SO Nightly code build"
  remote_user: root
  hosts: cleanroom
  tasks:
    - name: Set version
      set_fact:
        version: {{wget -O - -o /dev/null https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/brutusin/wava/maven-metadata.xml | grep -Po '(?<=<version>)([0-9\.]+(-SNAPSHOT)?)' | sort --version-sort -r| head -n 1}}
      debug var=version
```

Hoping to get the version so I can pass it through the rest of my playbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by running the wget as a shell and setting it as the output find code below

```
    - name: Set code version
      shell:  wget -O - -o /dev/null wget -O - -o /dev/null https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/brutusin/wava/maven-metadata.xml | grep -Po '(?<=<version>)([0-9\.]+(-SNAPSHOT)?)' | sort --version-sort -r| head -n 1
      register: shell_output

    - name: set version
      set_fact:
        code_version: "{{ shell_output.stdout }}"
        debug: var=code_version
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is (whatever the *version* will be).

```
- name: Set version
  set_fact:
    version: "{{ wget -O - -o /dev/null https:// ... }}"

- debug:
    var: version
```

Comment: ```      set_fact:
         version: " {{ wget -O - -o /dev/null https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/brutusin/wava/maven-metadata.xml | grep -Po '(?<=<version>)([0-9\.]+(-SNAPSHOT)?)' | sort --version-sort -r| head -n 1 }} "
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. 
```

The output I got from above